# Is there any alternative in Java ecosystem similar to cargo build in Rust?

Tags: java, build

I really like the way we compile and produce the executable in a nice simple way using `cargo` in Rust. Just typing `cargo run` takes care of building *and running* the program. The best part is that it is included in the Rust distribution. But in Java, is there any such batteries-included feature that allows us to achieve the same. For example, if I have a root directory named app and two sub-directories called bin and src. Inside of src, I have the standard package structure like com/company/main/java and then directories containing the code. So in the root directory, when I execute the command `javac`, is there any flag or command or config file that I need to use so that I get a compiler jar in the bin directory or at least the compiled class files in the bin directory in the same structure as the code is placed in src ?

NOTE : I am *not* looking for a build system like Maven, Gradle, etc. I am specifically looking forward to do this using just two commands that come with the JDK, javac and java.